# Is there a way to do rolling rank in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ranking, rank

I am trying to rank some values in one column over a rolling period of N days instead of having the ranking done over the entire set. I have seen several methods here using rolling_apply but I have read that this is no longer in python. For example, in the following table;

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2013 | 100 |
| 02-01-2013 | 85 |
| 03-01-2013 | 110 |
| 04-01-2013 | 60 |
| 05-01-2013 | 20 |
| 06-01-2013 | 40 |

For the column A above, how can I have the rank as below for N = 3;

|  | A | Ranked_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2013 | 100 | NaN |
| 02-01-2013 | 85 | Nan |
| 03-01-2013 | 110 | 1 |
| 04-01-2013 | 60 | 3 |
| 05-01-2013 | 20 | 3 |
| 06-01-2013 | 40 | 2 |

Answer (score 4):

Yes we have some work around, still with `rolling` but need `apply`

```
df.A.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False)[-1])
01-01-2013    NaN
02-01-2013    NaN
03-01-2013    1.0
04-01-2013    3.0
05-01-2013    3.0
06-01-2013    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the [-1] stand for? In my data, I get NaN as the result of the entire series if I set a large rolling window such as 30 or KeyError: -1 when the window is 6 or less.

Comment: @evacoder that is pick the last line of every rolling , since rolling is return a array

Comment: Thanks a bunch. After a lot of struggle, I finally managed to find a solution that  worked for my dataset with your help. I also realized I had a mistake on my table by sorting after I had applied the rolling rank formula which messed up the calculations.  
rank_pos = lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False).iloc[-1]

js_sales_raw['sales_rank'] = js_sales_raw['rate_of_sale_i'].rolling(window = 30,center=False).apply(rank_pos)

Comment: If performance is an issue you may want to look at this thread:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9481 and specifically  https://github.com/contribu/rollingrank.